# How to fetch diagram object of EA.Element

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

I have EA element. How can I get the Diagram object or Diagram id for the element's parent?
I am creating EA element through a tabular form. I want to programmatically add this element to the Diagram of parent element.
Parent element is already added to the diagram.

How can I get that parent diagram ?

Comment: An element does not have a "parent diagram". So, what are you looking for?

Comment: let me rephrase: I have an element whose corresponding diagram object is added to a "Diagram" . how can I create a new diagram object and add it to the "Diagram"?

Comment: You mean to the same diagram?

Comment: yes,same diagram.

Answer (score 0):

You can not legally place the same element twice in the same diagram. The automation still (I guess) allows to do it, but is has strange side effects, so you should not attempt it.

If for any reason you want to do so, you need to locate the diagram itself. Since an element can be in more than one diagram, you have to find the relevant diagram or deal with all diagrams where it is placed. To find them you can issue the following:

```
Repository.SQLquery("SELECT do.diagram_id FROM t_diagramobjects AS do INNER JOIN t_object ON do.Object_ID = t_object.Object_ID WHERE t_object.ea_guid = '{B979A0E9-17CB-4ed2-ADAB-D6FB3BE10A2B}'")
```

Just replace the example GUID with that of your object. In return you get a XML string that lists all diagram ids where the element is used. This query looks into all diagram objects where your element is used and returns the diagram id of the appropriate diagram.

Now you can do whatever evil you want to do with those diagrams.

Well, honestly there is a legal way to have an element twice on a diagram. This is by using a virtualized connector. I haven't used that (neither manually not per automation) so far except for a short manual test. I can have a look if you need that.

Comment: hi Thomas, thanks for your reply . I tried as suggested but I am getting below message: "SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing or the punctuation is incorrect"